# javascript drag and drop, dragging elements around the page is inaccurite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

so I have a canvas that takes up 100% of the page size and ontop of this canvas are other html elements. I want to make it so any element that has the class `game-gui` can be dragged round the screen (so users can position them where they want).

the js fiddle for this looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/VYJCj/2/

the code for this can be seen below:

```
$('.game-gui').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).on('dragstart', function(event){

        var left = parseInt($(obj).css("left"), 10);
        var top = parseInt($(obj).css("top"), 10);

        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

        var str = (left - event.originalEvent.clientX) + ',' + (top - event.originalEvent.clientY)+ ',' + event.target.id;
        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", str);
    });
});

this.canvas = $('#game_canvas');

this.canvas.bind('drop', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var offset = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');

    console.log(offset);

    var obj = $('#' + offset[2]);
    var clientX = event.originalEvent.clientX || 0;
    var clientY = event.originalEvent.clientY || 0 ;


    obj.css('left', ( clientX+ parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px');
    obj.css('top', ( clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px');

    return false;
});

this.canvas.bind('dragover', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    return false; 
});
```

as you will be able to see from the demo you can move the elements around the page however they move into different positions then they should! would anyone be able to help me on the matter?

Comment: You sure it's not just dropping the element top left at where the cursor is?  It doesn't adjust for where you click within the draggable automatically

Comment: I'm 100% sure on this, it becomes a lot easier to see this on a larger screen. The chat seems to move fine, however you can see this problem on the friends list

Comment: One problem I found was that in your dragstart, sometimes your 'top' is NaN.  Does fix the whole problem, but its a start.